# Confused about attaching/detaching entities in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework, I encounter some attach/detach errors when I need it to write changes to the database.

First here's how I get the records from my repository:

```
public PublishedApplication GetPublishedApplication(int id)
{
    return dal.ExecuteFirstOrDefault(
        context.PublishedApplication.Include("Customers")
        .Where(w => w.Id == id));
}
```

Note that this is not being detached, and it has MergeOption = AppendOnly.

Another place, I call a method in my repo to attach a customer to the application:

```
public void AttachCustomer(int applicationId, int customerId)
{
    var app = new PublishedApplication{ Id = applicationId};
    var customer = new Customer { Id = customerId};

    try
    {
        context.AttachTo("PublishedApplication", app);
        context.AttachTo("Customer ", customer );

        app.Customers.Add(customer);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

This, of course, gives me an error that the objects (app and customer) are already attached to an object context.

So I need to detach my objects in my repository. This is also more correct as I don't need to throw "query related information" around the web. But how can I do this? If I detach the entity in my `GetPublishedApplication` method, my graph of related data is lost, and I can't afford that. I need that graph elsewhere on my site. Can't use merge option `NoTracking` either.

So what options do I have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say you can't use NoTracking.

Wonder why not? This seems ideal for your needs.

Comment: It seems like on the one hand you want your entities detached? I.e. so you get 'No change Tracking'. But then you say you can't use NoTracking Merge Option?

That seems wierd to me.

Alex

Comment: If I set NoTracking, wouldn't it still track the related graph of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there isn't easy solution for reattaching entities.
May be this post will help you:
[Reattaching Entity Graphs with the Entity Framework on codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/attachobjectgraph.aspx)